# What is latxpar?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence:

> Note that it is not mandatory to specify both the `plus` and the `minus` values, but if you do, `latxpar` must be placed before `minus`.

... here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Length_manipulation

I googled `latxpar` but couldn't find anything explaining what it is.

Can anyone enlighten what `latxpar` is?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me: '`plus`  must be placed before `minus`' would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @JosephWright i checked the article's history. If it's a typo, it's been around since the `09:08, 30 December 2012` edit. http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Lengths&oldid=2470266

Comment: Quite possibly, but then the wikibook does have quite a number of odd things in it.

Comment: @JosephWright, You're absolutely right! It IS a typo! I checked the `19:45, 29 December 2012‎` edit (http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Lengths&oldid=2470132), it wrote: "Note that it is not mandatory to specify both the plus and the minus values, but if you do, plus must be placed before minus." Wow!

Comment: @JosephWright, If it wasn't for your "typo" comment, I wouldn't have thought of checking the article's history. Thank you! :D